# In C, how to match d_type value to "state" of element?

Tags: c

I am listing elements in a directory in C.

I use the following code:

```
struct dirent *dir_entry;

DIR *dr = opendir(argv[path_arg_index]);
while ((dir_entry = readdir(dr)) != NULL) {
    printf("%s - %u \n", dir_entry->d_name, dir_entry->d_type);
}
```

Which prints:

```
build - 4 
src - 4 
.. - 4 
README.md - 8 
.gitignore - 8 
. - 4 
.git - 4
```

Considering the output, 4 represents a directory, 8 a file.

But from some documentations (like [here](http://manpagesfr.free.fr/man/man3/readdir.3.html)), there are more than two different values d_type can take.

Two questions related to this:

- why do I get digits/numbers are values and not things like "DT_DIR" as stated in the link above ?
- How to know which "numerical" values is linked to the possible values stated in the link above ?

Comment: You get numbers because they’re defined as numbers. You compare them to the definitions (`DT_DIR` etc) and you don’t need to know what the numbers are behind the definitions and it will work everywhere.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Indeed. Autocompletion also shows it to me. I should have checked that. Thanks.  Make an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Because of #define DT_DIR 0x04 and #define DT_FILE 0x08 propably. You can write a function. char *print_dType(uint8_t type) { switch (type) { case DT_DIR: return "DIR"; break; ...}}, something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Values because they are enums.
   ref: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.7-4.6/+/refs/heads/jb-dev/sysroot/usr/include/dirent.h
2. Types are not consistent across OS so need to check "dirent.h" or "sys/types.h" of that OS.
   ref: https://c-for-dummies.com/blog/?p=3252

You can also use stat function to know if its a file or directory from "sys/stat.h"

below example in case you want to print file or dir:

```
struct dirent *dir_entry;
DIR *dr = opendir(argv[path_arg_index]);
while( (dir_entry = readdir(dr)) )
{
    stat(entry->d_name,&filestat);
    if( S_ISDIR(filestat.st_mode) )
        printf("%4s: %s\n","Dir", dir_entry->d_name);
    else
        printf("%4s: %s\n","File", dir_entry->d_name);
}
closedir(folder);
```

Comment: `stat(entry->d_name` hm.... you should go with `fstatat(dirfd(dr), entry->d_name, &filestat, 0)`. name is only name, without path.